# How to use Django's generic view to authenticate

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to do what it says in this link:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.login

So in the link provided above, where it talks about "URL name: login", in the optional arguments it says:

> "redirect_field_name: The name of a GET field containing the URL to redirect to after login. Overrides next if the given GET parameter is passed."

How do I specify what next is? If you scroll a bit more down, it says

> "... the view redirects to the URL specified in next. If next isn’t provided, it redirects to settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL".

How do I specify what next is and what `settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` is?

Also, it would be great and helpful if someone can give an example of how to use the generic view to authenticate, but if not, that's fine, as long as the question above gets answered. I know they gave an example of a template but I want an example of how to create the actual view and use it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `urls.py` looks similar to this:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'mywebsite.index', name='index'),
    url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout_then_login', name='logout')
)
```

Then in your settings file, put something like this:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'index'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGOUT_URL = 'logout'
```

Which will cause the login page to redirect to the `mywebsite.index` view (since the `name='index'` matches this view, and that's what we set in `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`.)

> I know they gave an example of a template but I want an example of how to create the actual view and use it.

The "actual view" is provided by django at `django.contrib.auth.views.login`, so you don't need to create the view at all. That's the whole point of the section you're reading. You provide the template, that template posts to the view, and then the view redirects to `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`.

Now when you use the [@login_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required) decorator, django will redirect the users to your login template via the built in django login view.

Comment: Hm okay, so if I want to redirect to a URL if the form is not valid / if the username does not match the password, where would I specify where to redirect to? I was just looking at django.contrib.auth.views.login and there is an if form.is_valid() statement but there is no else statement on if it is not valid.. should I just add it in the view saying if it isn't valid, then redirect to another url?

Comment: @user2817200 if it's not valid it will just return to the login page with the appropriate form errors, which is what you (generally) want.